# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with SimplecursorAdapter and ListView

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, indexoutofboundsexception

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this, please help. Only thing I can tell is that if I comment out `setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);`, the code runs but nothing appears on my `ListView`. Any other part of the code that could be useful let me know. Thank you for your help.

```
08-06 03:21:50.435: E/AndroidRuntime(489): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:157)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1147)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1060)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-06 03:21:50.565: E/AndroidRuntime(489):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My activity:

```
public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity {
final String APP_TAG = "RouteTracker";

boolean APP_DEBUG = true;
int searchType;

DbAdapter dbAdapter;

Context context = this;

@Override
public void onResume(){
    dbAdapter.open();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    dbAdapter.close();
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle);

    if (APP_DEBUG) {Log.d(APP_TAG, "Inside onCreate for SearchActivity");}

    dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);

    Bundle searchActivityBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    searchType = searchActivityBundle.getInt("SearchType");

    TextView titleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.search_activity_title_label);
    titleLabel.setText(getString(R.string.search_activity_default_title_label));

    final EditText search_criteria_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_activity_search_criteria_edittext);

    Button search_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_activity_search_button);
    search_button.setText(getString(R.string.search_activity_search_button));

    //ListView searchResultsList; // = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    //searchResultsList = getListView();

    switch (searchType) {
    case RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_NAME:
        search_criteria_edittext.setHint(getString(R.string.search_activity_textview_company_name_hint));
        break;
    case RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_STREET:
        search_criteria_edittext.setHint(getString(R.string.search_activity_textview_street_hint));
        break;
    case RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_CITY:
        search_criteria_edittext.setHint(getString(R.string.search_activity_textview_city_hint));
        break;
    case RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_STATE:
        search_criteria_edittext.setHint(getString(R.string.search_activity_textview_state_hint));
        break;
    case RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_ZIP:
        search_criteria_edittext.setHint(getString(R.string.search_activity_textview_zip_hint));
        break;
    }

    search_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String searchCriteria = search_criteria_edittext.getText().toString();
            if (searchCriteria.trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No data entered, try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            String[] columns = new String[] {};
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.search_activity_details_search_results, R.id.search_activity_details_company_name};

            Cursor dataCursor;

            switch (searchType) {
            case RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_NAME:
                dataCursor = dbAdapter.search(searchType, searchCriteria); 
                columns= new String[] {"CompanyName"};
                break;
            case RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_STREET:
                dataCursor = dbAdapter.search(searchType, searchCriteria);
                columns = new String[] {"AddressStreet","CompanyName"};
                break;
            case RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_CITY:
                dataCursor = dbAdapter.search(searchType, searchCriteria);
                columns = new String[] {"AddressCity", "CompanyName"};
                break;
            case RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_STATE:
                dataCursor = dbAdapter.search(searchType, searchCriteria);
                columns = new String[] {"AddressState", "CompanyName"};
                break;
            case RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_ZIP:
                dataCursor = dbAdapter.search(searchType, searchCriteria);
                columns = new String[] {"AddressZip", "CompanyName"};
                break;
            default:
                dataCursor = dbAdapter.search(RouteTrackerGlobal.SEARCH_NAME, searchCriteria);
                columns = new String[] {"", "CompanyName"};
                break;
            }
            startManagingCursor(dataCursor);

            if (dataCursor == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Something happened that failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setListAdapter(null);
                return;
            }
            if (dataCursor.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.search_activity_no_results), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setListAdapter(null);
                return;
            }
            SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.search_activity_details, dataCursor, columns, to);
            setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);

            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), dataCursor.getColumnName(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }});
```

I loaded android 2.1 source and was able to find where it fails but I still dont understand it.

It fails in the SimpleCursorAdapter class inside bindView.  Below is bindView, it fails in  **String text = cursor.getString(from[i]);**

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final View[] holder = mHolders.get(view);
    final ViewBinder binder = mViewBinder;
    final int count = mTo.length;
    final int[] from = mFrom;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View v = holder[i];
        if (v != null) {
            boolean bound = false;
            if (binder != null) {
                bound = binder.setViewValue(v, cursor, from[i]);
            }

            if (!bound) {
                **String text = cursor.getString(from[i]);**
                if (text == null) {
                    text = "";
                }

                if (v instanceof TextView) {
                    setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                    setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                            " view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you highlight the exact line that is throwing this error?

Comment: that's the problem, I cant.  All lines in my code run, when I press the search_button  everything executes, my dataCursor gets populated from my dbAdapter.query, my cursorAdapter is initiated and even setListAdapter(cursorAdapter) appears to run since the Toast.makeText (after setListAdapter) gets executed, but somewhere in the background something fails.  When I comment out setListAdapter(cursorAdapter) I dont get the crash but my listview doesn't get populated either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using the variable i to count through the length of your mTo array.  Are you certain that the size of mTo is not greater than the size of from[] or holder[]? Because if you want to access all of those arrays at i, you better make sure they all have the same number of elements, otherwise you are just asking for trouble.

Comment: The BindView method is not mine but android original source.  After going thru that it somehow clicked that what could be the problem was the from and columns relationship.  For those who come up with this same problem.  I made the mistake of passing one column to my listview but expecting 2 textviews to bind to it.